# How do I read each of arrays which saved inside list which again is inside column of the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

So, I have bounding boxes "xy xy" saved inside this particular column(bounding_boxes) of the data frame and now I am trying to extract all three arrays out from the first rows but don't how!

The input I have looks like this:

```
"[array([     1178.4,      1.6609,      1532.1,      935.91], dtype=float32), array([     761.56,      386.14,      953.42,      936.99], dtype=float32), array([      458.4,      544.93,      1014.9,      943.33], dtype=float32)]"
```

```
output:
 a = [     1178.4,      1.6609,      1532.1,      935.91]
 b = [     761.56,      386.14,      953.42,      936.99]
 c = [      458.4,      544.93,      1014.9,      943.33]
```

Input files look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as every cell has the same number of elements, you can just create a simple custom string parser.

```py
s = "one_particular_cell_string"

s = [i for i in s.replace("[", " ").replace("]", " ").replace(",", " ").split(" ") if len(i) > 0]

ls = []
for i in s:
    try:
        ls.append(float(i))
    except ValueError:
        pass

ls = np.reshape(ls, (3, 4))
```

You could also use `eval()` but usually you shouldn't unless you absolutely trust your input.
In that case you could do

```
from numpy import float32, array
x = eval(s) # gives:  list[np.array]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I am going to use ```eval``` as the number of arrays isn't going to be the same.